# Set video metadata after uploading to vimeo

Tags: ios, video, metadata, vimeo, vimeo-api

I've successfully uploaded video to vimeo by using API V3. Now, i want to set few metadata likes name, description, privacy.view etc to uploaded video.

When i tried with vimeo playground, it get success: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#/{video_id}

But in code, i tried following two way but didn't get success.

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@videos/%@?access_token=%@&name=%@&description=%@&privacy.view=%@", VIMEO_API_CALL_URL, strVideoID, VIMEO_ACCESS_TOKEN_TEMP, strName, strDescription, strPrivacyView];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"PATCH"];
```

and following also,

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@videos/%@?access_token=%@", VIMEO_API_CALL_URL, strVideoID, VIMEO_ACCESS_TOKEN_TEMP];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"PATCH"];

[request setValue:@"iOS_QuickTime" forHTTPHeaderField:@"name"];
[request setValue:@"This video is uploaded via iOS applcation and to perform last step by adding all required metadata." forHTTPHeaderField:@"description"];
[request setValue:@"nobody" forHTTPHeaderField:@"privacy.view"];
```

Here, VIMEO_API_CALL_URL is "https://api.vimeo.com/";

I'm wandering for solution. Till if any one can help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Your access token should be included in a proper authentication header. Something like this:

`Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxtokenxxxxxxx`

The values you are trying to set (title, description, privacy) should be query params, not header key / values. So your first approach is correct.

You could also consider using the Vimeo iOS SDK (I'm one of the authors) or just browse the codebase to help you get from point A to point B:

https://github.com/vimeo/VIMNetworking

Feel free to file issues on that repo too.

Comment: Alfie Hanssen : I also tried with your suggestion and set [request setValue:@"Bearer <TOKEN>" forKey:@"Authorization"];
but it still not giving result.